# .NET MVC 4 Custom Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Im doing a new .NET project using MVC 4

It will have a lot of repeating content, and I was wondering if that is best done using Custom Controls or if they aren't really used any more.

If not what is the best practice to do something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give a very good answer without a more specific description of what is involved in "a lot of repeating content".

However I believe there are two things in particular that you should learn about which should answer this question sufficiently.

The first is Helpers. This can come in the form of HtmlHelpers and Razor helpers. Learn both.

The second is Partial Views. They're amazingly helpful for repetitive content and will often solve problems where you feel like you don't want to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1):

check with below link. it might be helpful for u

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32356/Custom-controls-in-ASP-NET-MVC